How can I make a TextField in Flutter automatically move to the next line when typing?
I'm using a TextField in Flutter and want to control the line wrapping behavior. How can I set the maxLines property or adjust the textInputAction and keyboardType to achieve this?
TextField(
  controller: _messageController,
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Type a message',
    border: InputBorder.none,
  ),
)

Using this code while typing, it's continuing horizontally but I need to automatically make a new line once reached the end of the typing space available.

Try below code...
          TextField(
              controller: _messageController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                 hintText: 'Type a message',
                 border: InputBorder.none,
                 filled: true,
                 fillColor: Colors.grey,
                ),
              maxLines: null, 
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline, 
            ),


Try using TextFormField instead of TextField:
TextFormField {
  controller: _messageController;
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Type a message',
    border: InputBorder.none,
  ),
}

